# Ubuntu Guest on Virtual Box keeps crashing

Tags: virtualbox, crash, ubuntu-10.10

Hi I have a Windows 7 Host, with following specs

- 4GB RAM
- i3 processor
- 500GB HD

(any other detail required? If so please ask.)

I have Virtual Box v3.2.12

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 on Virtual Box with 1GB RAM and 32GB HD

While it boots up fine, i have used it for several months, but from the start (of installing) the Ubuntu just crashes. As in not responding. The only option then I am left with is to **Turn off power** and lose all work.

I do simple stuff like Internet browsing, programming etc. on Ubuntu. The crash occurs after around 30Mins to 1 hour.

Tell me what can I do to prevent this?

Do i need to upgrade both of them (virtual box and ubuntu)?

Should i create partition for ubuntu instead? (this is my last resort)

Do I need to increase the RAM for Ubuntu? Or there is some setting to be tinkered?

Thanks!

Comment: Post ubuntu's kernel log and maybe virtualbox's vm log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alway dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 instead of running Ubuntu inside a VM on windows. It will run a lot faster that way.

However I'll add that I've never had a problem running Ubuntu VMs in Windows 7.  As was suggested by Billc, you should check the virtualbox logs and if they are fine then you should check /var/log/syslog (searching for entries from the time when the crash happened).

Comment: Yep, I just installed Ubuntu in partition. That's the best way to use Ubuntu.

Comment: Glad you found something that works well for you. :)